# Maximum size of multiset of integers without subset summing to zero.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider multisets of integers in the range $[-m,+m]$.
The sum of the elements is 0, but no strict non-empty sub-multiset has sum 0.
For example $\{+3, -1, -1, -1\}$ for $m \ge 3$.

The question I've run into is what is the largest possible such multiset given $m$.

With $m=3$ we can construct $\{+3, +3, -2, -2, -2\}$.
This belongs to a family of multisets with $(m-1)$ copies of $m$ and $m$ copies of $-(m-1)$, with a net $2m - 1$ elements.
I do not know if these represent the largest family, however.

This feels like the sort of problem which is reducible to a known number theory or combinatorics problem, though I'm not familiar enough with the field to know what they would be called.

Comment: Changed language to reflect that, thanks.